# VBA - Macro finish much faster when I click during the process

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro with this loop which take a lot of time :

```
Dim tempval As String
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For row = 2 To 500 Step 1
        tempval = ""
        For col = 7 To 15 Step 1
            tempval = tempval & Cells(row, col).Value
            Cells(row, col).Value = ""
        Next col
        Cells(row, 7).Value = tempval

        For col = 8 To 16 Step 1
        tempval = tempval & Cells(row, col).Value
        Cells(row, col).Value = ""
    Next col
    Cells(row, 8).Value = tempval

    Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("LibAnglais2:LibAnglais9").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("LibFrancais2:LibFrancais9").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

There is code, before, and after this loop.
With this loop, the code takes 3 minutes to end. Without, it takes 30s.
But when I click on the excel windows during the loop (You know when a program run, you click, the window become a white blur screen), my macro finish after I clicked and take approximately 45s...

Do you have an idea why ? And how can fix this to have a faster macro ?

Comment: Maybe Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual helps (before the loop)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Try to add DoEvents before Next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with a variant array loaded in bulk directly from the worksheet. Use the [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for your concatenation (`Chr(124)` is the 'pipe' character) and return the processed values back to the worksheet *en masse*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sonic()
    Dim r As Long, vTMPs() As Variant, vVALs() As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        vTMPs = .Range("G2:P500").Value2
        ReDim vVALs(LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1), LBound(vTMPs, 2) To 2)
        For r = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            vVALs(r, 1) = Join(Array(vTMPs(r, 1), vTMPs(r, 2), vTMPs(r, 3), vTMPs(r, 4), _
                                     vTMPs(r, 5), vTMPs(r, 6), vTMPs(r, 7), vTMPs(r, 8)), Chr(124))
            vVALs(r, 2) = Join(Array(vTMPs(r, 2), vTMPs(r, 3), vTMPs(r, 4), vTMPs(r, 5), _
                                     vTMPs(r, 6), vTMPs(r, 7), vTMPs(r, 8), vTMPs(r, 9)), Chr(124))
        Next r
        .Range("G2:P500").ClearContents
        .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'I don't know what the following is supposed to do
        .Range("LibAnglais2:LibAnglais9").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("LibFrancais2:LibFrancais9").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes VBA needs to process messages to be faster. I don't really know why but if some of my macros act up like that I add a `DoEvents` line in the loop before the `Next` and it does wonders. It is not recommended for more complex applications. Here you can find a description of it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DoEvents-Function-7af41eca-88e0-470d-adaf-0b3d4c2575b0

So your code would be:

```
DoEvents
Next row
```

HTH

Comment: if a simple `cells(a,b).value=""` slows your computer, change it. `doevents`will slow down your macro even more in this particulary case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so, I found the solution.
In fact, I had a other sub in my code :

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

And the code pass on this sub each time a cell was modified.
So I put a :

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

On my code, and it's work !
Thank's for your help !

EDIT : In fact, the problem is not totally solved... I noticed that the code take a lot of time after saving the worksheet or simply after modifiying the code... Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Do you need this event at all? Because if you don't, you can just simply delete it.

Comment: Well, okay, than, glad you found it.

Comment: enableevents is not the only issue. Instead of clearing the cells independantly (in a loop), you should clear the whole range at the end of the mini-loops. Using Arrays would improve a lot the execution time too. The second miniloop does nothing because it passes to the same cells already cleared at the first miniloop, `Cells(row, 8).Value = tempval & cells(row,16).value` alone does the same

Comment: You are right, but in fact, i need theses two miniloop, because I Have 18 columns, and the first and the 10th are the final columns after concatenate all other. Imagine, in my file, I have FR1|FR2|FR3|EN1|EN2|EN3, FR1 take FR2 and FR3 after concatenating, and same for EN1, EN2 and EN3.